# WIndows 7 Live Mail Server Config: Clear Text Authentication

Tags: mail-server, windows-live-mail

I've been following instructions to configure the mail server, noticing they all suggest using "Log on using clear text authentication" setting.

What are the ramifications of that? I wouldn't want to send my credentials in clear text, if that's what this setting implies :)

Comment: If it's going via SSL oder TLS then everything is OK, if you don't use TLS or SSL, then your password will get in clear text over the line.

Comment: @AndréSchild, that makes sense. Is there a way to check if SSL/TLS is being used (without packet inspection tools)?